# How to generate a list of number, in a range?

Tags: python, list, numbers, range

I do not understand how to generate a list of number, in a range?
So far I have:

```
    numberslist1=sum([range(1, 1000)])
    for x in range(len(numberslist1)):
        print(numberslist1[x])
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: Because it doesn't make any sense. `numberslist1` is trying to sum over a list that has a single `range` object in it. Do you want `for x in range(sum(range(1, 1000))): print(x)` (note that this will print the best part of half a million integers)?

Comment: It doesn't work because you can not `sum` a range object, but what are you actually trying to do? Are you trying to generate a list of the sums of integers from 1 to _n_?, e.g. if `n = 10` -> `[0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]`

Comment: Also `sum([5,2,8])` is a number. E.g. `len(6)` would raise `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `range` function returns a generator, but you can convert this to a list as follows:

```
numbers = list(range(1, 1000))
```

Answer (score 1):

example:

```
a = range(1, 100)
print a
```

Comment: This is for Python 2.7, OP is using Python 3.x